# Centering a DIV containing unknown number of floating divs

Tags: html, css, css-float

I've read many posts on how to center a div of unknown width containing floatings divs of unknown number in another div, but all of them assume that the contained floating divs don't flow to more than one line, or they don't need to line up into nice columns.

Assuming this layout:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="box">content</div>
    <div class="box">content</div>

    ... many more (unknown number) of div.box ...

    <div class="box">content</div>
    <div class="box">content</div>
</div>
```

where div.box has a fixed height/width, floating them left makes them line up nicely, and fill the available space as div.container is re-sized. I would like div.container to be centered however.

If I use the following, the div.box elements will all line up nicely and the div.container will be nicely centered, but the final line of divs won't line up with the left side of the other lines. They will be centered, and out of their columns.

```
.container {
    text-align:center;
}

.box {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

The width of div.container is variable, so using something like this is not an option:

```
.container {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.box {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Any ideas or suggestions ?

Comment: Do you have any image describing what exactly do you mean by "line up"?

Comment: If you look at http://jsfiddle.net/DomDay/axUBx/ , you see a standard float:left, where all content boxes always line up in a grid when you resize the window, with the last row floated left. This is exactly what I want, except I'd like the entire grid centered horizontally. Using this simple float:left, the margin grows on the right until there is room for another content box column.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that becuase the container has a dynamic width - `margin: 0 auto` won't work.

We can fix this by using `media queries` for this.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/LhPTF/2/)**

So lets say each box has a width of 200px the media queries will look something like:

```
@media (min-width: 210px) {
    ul{
        width: 200px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 410px) {
    ul{
        width: 400px;
    }
}
...

...
```

Now that this is in place - `margin: 0 auto` on the container div works like it should.

Comment: That's a great approach, and would work perfectly if it was known what else was in the browser taking up space to the left and right of the container at any given time. The media query is based on the entire viewport, right ?

Comment: Yes,the media query is based on the entire viewport. If you know the width of your sidebars, you could take this into account in your media queries.

Comment: I've given it some thought, and given that the grid layout is implemented for all listable data types on the site ( 6 and growing ) whose content box dimensions differ per data type, with teaser, mini, and full versions of each, the special case coding for the media query approach are multiplying. The lovely thing about the float:left grid is that it requires no special cases regardless of box size and container size. You made me look into media queries though. +1 for that. hah

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [box-sizing](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#box-sizing0) property to constrain the padding and border areas to the dimensions of the content box,
 e.g.

```
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eNT2d/3/

Comment: Hi, I'm having trouble thinking of a way that changing the box model will help solve this problem. Am I missing something obvious ?

Answer (score 0):

add this

```
.container {
  text-align:center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

and make sure the parent div for the container has a width of 100%.